# Titan - Faunus - Gremlin Examples

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, titan

i want use Titan with Cassandra as graph database (with Faunus as Framework). Where can i get example codes for Faunus or Gremlin? I want to query the pagerank algo on the Graüh DB?

Answer (score 1):

Try their Official Wiki Pages :

For **Titan with Cassandra**: [See Here](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Using-Cassandra)

For **Basic Gremlin Query**: [See Here](http://gremlindocs.com/)

For **Faunus Implementation**: [Titan Format](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/faunus/wiki/Titan-Format), [Faunus Graph](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/faunus/wiki/Faunus-Graph)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Titan 1.0, You should avoid using Faunus, as [it is buggy] -- it just does not retrieve all vertices from the [graph](https://tinkerpop.apache.org).

Unfortunately, there is no other good solution for using Titan with Hadoop.
If you are familiar with Spark, try SparkGraphComputer which is part of TinkerPop.